# How to combine arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arrayOne = [a,b,c];  
var arrayTwo = [d,e,f];
```

How can I combine the two arrays in JavaScript so that the result will be:

```
var array = [a,d,b,e,c,f];
```

*Note: This is not concatenating two arrays. This is merging the two arrays so the indices look like `[0,0,1,1,2,2]`.*

Comment: var arrayTre = arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo );

Comment: apologies - the edit has clarified.  You'd be looking for something like underscore.js's `_.zip` function.

Comment: I do not agree to these downvotes! +1 because of unnecessary downvoting. She did not say that she wanted to concatenate arrays. Even if she did it wouldn't be a reason to downvote.

Comment: @NoelWidmer not that I've down voted, but to be fair this is still an extremely elementary question.

Comment: +1 This question is a good example showcasing how many people (even high rep) don't read questions thoroughly enough, but are quick to vote and close.

Comment: @Alnitak Indeed it is. But people can mark as duplicate if there is an equivalent. Downvoting shouldn't be used for marking elementary questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two arrays are equal of length, this should do the trick:

```
var arrayThree = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
   arrayThree.push(arrayOne[i], arrayTwo[i]);
}
```

If they aren't the same length and you would have the two arrays:

```
var a = [a,b,c,d];
var b = [e,f];
```

I assume you would want the the following result

```
var c = [a,e,b,f,c,d];
```

That should do the trick:

```
var c = [];
while(Math.min(a.length, b.length)){
   c = c.concat(a.splice(0,1), b.splice(0,1));
   //Or c = c.concat(b.splice(0,1), a.splice(0,1));
   //depending on the order
}
a.length ? c = c.concat(a) : c = c.concat(b);
//Here is a = [c,d] and b = []
```

Comment: So, what if they aren't the same length?

Comment: There is one important thing that is worth mentioning: a and b will be empty at the end  of this operation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery's unique method along with concat

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [2,3,4];
var c = a.concat(b); // [1,2,3,2,3,4]
c = $.unique(c); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You may need to sort the array as needed.

Comment: This does not address the question since it's about combining arrays and not about uniqueness of to concatenated arrays.